# Proguard errors when exporting Android project after updating to ADT 20

Tags: android, adt, proguard

After updating to ADT 20 I can no longer successfully export any of my Android projects. I get:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
```

In the console I get tons of the `can't find referenced class` warnings and occasionally the `can't find superclass or interface` warning. At the end of the warnings I get something like this:

```
    You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Warning: there were 199 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
    You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
 at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
 at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
 at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
 at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Each time I attempt to build I get different numbers of warnings (it's not very consistent). Also, when I perform a clean before export, the export completes without producing any warnings, but the resulting APK crashes on launch often due to `ClassNotFoundException`.

My `proguard-project.txt` includes the necessary `-keep class` rules for the Android Support Library and ActionBarSherlock.

I had no problems building this project before ADT 20. I even tried building my last release (which obviously built fine when I released it), but I get the same proguard warnings and failed export.

I've tried adding `-libraryjars` and/or `-dontwarn` rules as many other SO questions suggest, but to no avail. It will sometimes build successfully, but the APK created crashes on launch.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I also tried updating from proguard 4.7 (which ships with the r20 tools) to proguard 4.8, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I was able to finally successfully build and run an obfuscated APK after adding the proguard rules that were removed from `proguard-android.txt` in the r20 Android tools to my `proguard-project.txt`. Waiting to confirm this is a bug before posting an answer: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35107

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug in AAPT where it will only process

```
<fragment android:name"..." />
```

but not

```
<fragment class="..." />
```

We'll fix AAPT but in the meantime you can use the other attribute and it'll work.

Comment: A fix to aapt has just been released. It's in platform-tools r14.

Comment: Had to clear my SDK Manager cache as suggested by Tor Norbye ("SDK Manager cache bug") before platform-tools r14 would show up.

Answer (score 4):

In ADT 20, we use a feature of aapt (see the -G flag) which can create a proguard file which contains keep rules for **exactly** the custom views used by your code.

The old proguard config files would keep **all** views. When you used a library project such as the compatibility library, where you might be using only a small subset of the available code, this could end up including a lot of stuff you don't need. By removing the generic keep rules, and adding a new keep file based on your application, your .apks would get smaller since a lot of unused stuff can be removed.

One area where this can go wrong is if you update to Tools 20 (so you have the new smaller proguard-android.txt file), and you continue to use ADT 18. Make sure to use ADT 20, since it will add in not just the proguard files specified in your project.properties setting, but the generated proguard file listing the keep files from aapt -G as well. I believe the ant build will also use the -G feature.

(Note - see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35107 for any followups on this)

Answer (score 0):

Reportedly, there are problems with a recent update of the Eclipse plugin in the ADT, which doesn't properly recompile all source code. In that case, ProGuard will print out warnings about your program classes (as opposed to the library classes). You should check if the export (and the resulting application) works without ProGuard. You should also check if the Ant build works ("ant release"). That could then be a workaround.

Comment: There are no problems building if I disable proguard. I will look into building directly with ant. Where have you seen reports of problems with the latest ADT update? I've been having trouble finding anything for r20, only previous versions which I had no problems with.

Comment: I setup the project for an Ant build and I don't receive any warnings or errors when I build with `ant release`, however the resulting APK crashes on launch (`ClassNotFoundException` on a class that extends a support library Fragment). As I stated in the question, I have the appropriate `-keep class` rules in my `proguard-project.txt` for the Android support library and ActionBarSherlock (bottom of http://abs.io/faq.html) and I haven't had any problems with proguard removing or obfuscating these classes before...any ideas what I could be missing (or possibly what the tools could be doing)?